# How to do a bold 1 (\mathbbm{1}) in MathJax

Tags: mathjax

I'm looking for **blackboard bold numerals** in LaTeX displayed with MathJax.
It seems that the `\mathbbm` command is not (yet) available from MathJax (as [said in the documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#m)).

Is there anyway to have support for the `\mathbbm` command, e.g., to have nice bold 1 ?
I tried to load an extension, or trick from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88734/), but nothing works.

Here is an example showing the failure: [with makebigmaths](http://perso.crans.org/besson/makebigmaths/?tex=%5Ctext%7BTEST%3A%7D%20%5C%5C%0A%5Cmathbbm%7B1%7D&size=2).

[image: example imgur.com/kBvIbpsl.png]

It seems to be [a known and old issue of MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/792), coming from a font limitation.
And no [third party extensions](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-third-party-extensions) seem to solve it.

However, [Jupyter notebooks](https://www.jupyter.org/) supports it in its Markdown cells.

Comment: You might want to clarify that you're after blackboard bold numerals.

Answer (score 13):

You can use Unicode characters directly, e.g., , or via the non-standard macro `\unicode{x1D7D9}`.

Both of these can be used in macro definitions as well, cf. http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros.

Answer (score 0):

One can use \Bbb instead of \mathbbm which is mentioned under "Font control" [in the current documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/textmacros.html). Judging by the question [Obsolete command \Bbb](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51530/obsolete-command-bbb), it is an obsolete TeX command.

I use \Bbb in an align environment using MathJax version 3.2.2 for doxygen.